# I'm trying to arrange my listview alphabetically

Tags: java, android, file, listview

I have a listview and it contains the songs but when I try to sort it by the alphabet, Its placement has changed but when it is clicked it still takes the old position, how to position it? is my code.

```
 final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    items = new String[mySongs.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
    items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".wav", "");
          }

         final CustomList adp = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, items, imageId);
    adp.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });
          lv.setAdapter(adp);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class).putExtra("pos", position).putExtra("songlist", mySongs));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anime_enter, R.anim.anime_exit);

   } 
    });

public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (File singleFile : files) {
        if (singleFile.isDirectory() && singleFile.isHidden()) {
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
        } else {
            if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
                    al.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Thank !

Comment: What do you mean by : `but the item selection still uses the old layout,` ?

Comment: Its placement has changed but when it is clicked it still takes the old position

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sorting list `items` and onClick you are passing `.putExtra("songlist", mySongs)`

Pass the same list object on `oClick`.

Comment: How can I pass the same object?, mySongs is an ArrayList <File>, if not passed mySongs then Player.java will fail.